# Three complex numbers are in AP

Tags: complex-numbers

Let's say $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are three complex numbers in AP. Does that mean they lie on a circle in the complex plane?

So, $z_2 = \frac{z_1 + z_3}{2}$

$z_2$ is the midpoint of $z_1$ and $z_3$. It means they are collinear, so they lie on a line.

Is that information enough?

What if $z_2$ is the midpoint of $z_1$ and $z_3$ and they lie on an arc?

This is my doubt!

Comment: I don't see how an arithmetic progression would imply a circle (unless you include a line as the degenerate case of infinite radius). Take $z_1=1,z_2=2,z_3=3$ for example; I don't see how you could make a circle (of finite radius) through all three.

Comment: That the points are collinear is enough to deduce that they cannot possibly lie on the same circle.

Comment: What do you mean by AP?

Comment: @copper.hat Arithmetic progression

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio: How do you know what the OP meant? Note that sometimes a straight line is taken as a circle in the complex plane (cf. Möbius transformations).